# hibernate - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, sql, list, hibernate, jpa

I am getting index out of bound exception while executing this code. Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

```
Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
String sql = "select name from chapter_product where name = 'sample'";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
List results = query.list();
if(results .get(0)!=null) {
System.out.println("value:"+results.get(0));
}else {
System.out.println("no values");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably thrown here:

```
List results = query.list();
```

This means, that there is no such data in your database and the resulting list is empty, so you can't get the first element of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. The point you specified is where the issue lies. Now it worked.

Comment: @java_mechanic no problem, if it helps consider upvoting / marking as correct;)

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access empty list first element in this line.

You need to check for empty then u need to access the objects

Sample code

```
       if(!results.isEmpty()){

System.out.println("value:"+results.get(0));
}
else{
System.out.println("no values");

}
```

Comment: This could result in a NPE if `results` is null.

Comment: Since query.list(); won't ever return null  so there is no need to check for null.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is you are trying to access the 0th element from an empty list.

Your check should be :

```
if (results == null || results.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("no values");
} else {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It worked. I somehow missed the isEmpty option.

Comment: @java_mechanic: if my answer helped you, please accept the answer or add a vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(results .get(0)!=null && !results.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("value:"+results.get(0));
 }else {
 System.out.println("no values");
 }
```